# Pandas drop function: Unalignable boolean Series

Tags: pandas

I have two DataFrames. The first df0:

```
Name       CHR  MAPINFO     PMG         APA 
cg13869341  1   15865   0.8954256   0.8409144
cg14008030  1   18827   0.5941512   0.712414
cg12045430  1   29407   0.1110794   0.1302404
cg20826792  1   29425   0.177532    0.1304049
cg00381604  1   29435   0.09003246  0.04180672
cg20253340  1   68849   0.4738799   0.444899
```

end the second df1:

```
probe   Chromosome  Gstart  Gend
A_23_P11744     1   4363    39806
A_33_P3365932   1   4363    39806
A_32_P923011    1   24554   46081
```

I would like to iterate over df0["MAPINFO"] and drop rows that don't match condition and append the means to another df. My code is as followed:

```
for pos in df0['MAPINFO']:
    cond = (( pos < df1['Gstart']) & ( pos > df1['Gend']))
    print df0.drop(df0[cond].index.values).mean(axis=0, skipna=True, level=None)
```

which gives the following error message:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py:2021: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
"DataFrame index.", UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ferreirafm/bin/cpg_means.py", line 239, in <module>
main()
File "/home/ferreirafm/bin/cpg_means.py", line 231, in main
import2df(infprobe, infchrom)
File "/home/ferreirafm/bin/cpg_means.py", line 20, in import2df
df0.drop(df0[cond].index.values)#.mean(axis=0, skipna=True, level=None)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1995, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_array(key)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2027, in _getitem_array
key = _check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1017, in _check_bool_indexer
raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

I'm almost sure that such piece of code used to work in previous version of Pandas. However, I can't figure out whats going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Expected results:
Observe that the last row of df0 is gonna be dropped as df1 'MAPINFO' of the first line (15865) is outside the df1 range Gstart and Gend. So, the results is gonna be the means by columns of the non-dropped lines from df0 (means of PGM and APA). That is, the resulting df will be:

```
Name       CHR  MAPINFO     PMG         APA 
cg13869341  1   15865   0.8954256   0.8409144
cg14008030  1   18827   0.5941512   0.712414
cg12045430  1   29407   0.1110794   0.1302404
cg20826792  1   29425   0.177532    0.1304049
cg00381604  1   29435   0.09003246  0.04180672
```

The last row from df0 "cg20253340  1   68849   0.4738799   0.444899" is removed and the means by row is taken.

Comment: What are you expecting the answer to be? I don't *think* this code would have worked previously.

Comment: you are trying to index df0 by indicies from df1, this *might* work but is really odd as the boolean indices are not equal length to the array are trying to index, so it might be wrapping. you are certainly going to get an unexpected result.

Comment: @AndyHayden: Thanks for comment. See the EDIT for expected results.

Comment: Sorry to be fussy, but what is the expected result as a DataFrame? :)

Comment: @AndyHayden: have a look on EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to make bool index which implements inclusion criteria then just use it:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([["cg13869341", 1, 15865, 0.8954256, 0.8409144],
                                 ["cg14008030", 1, 18827, 0.5941512, 0.712414],
                                 ["cg12045430", 1, 29407, 0.1110794, 0.1302404],
                                 ["cg20826792", 1, 29425, 0.177532, 0.1304049],
                                 ["cg00381604", 1, 29435, 0.09003246, 0.04180672],
                                 ["cg20253340", 1, 68849, 0.4738799, 0.444899]],
                                columns = ["Name", "CHR", "MAPINFO", "PMG", "APA"])

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records([["A_23_P11744", 1, 4363, 39806],
                                 ["A_33_P3365932", 1, 4363, 39806],
                                 ["A_32_P923011", 1, 24554, 46081]],
                                columns = ["probe", "Chromosome", "Gstart", "Gend"])

F = df0.MAPINFO.apply(lambda x: ((df1.Gstart <= x) & (x <= df1.Gend)).any())
print df0[F] ## as you exepected

# mean by rows
res = df0[F]
res['mean'] = df0[F][['PMG', 'APA']].mean(1)
print res

# mean by columns
print df0[F][['PMG', 'APA']].mean(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your suggestion works just fine for the those dfs. I'm trying to modify your code to apply lambda function for each MAPINFO at once. Acctually, those df are huge.Best.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding: MAPINFO iteration is already part of df.MAPINFO.apply, it rather replacement of for loop. In this respect

Comment: I've got to adapt your suggestion for my needs. Thanks for helping.